# Как валидировать кастомный тип в FormBuilder?

Tags: symfony, symfony2, symfony-form, formbuilder

Мне нужно чтобы form->isValid срабатывало и для кастомного типа

в общем есть

```
class FastUserRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'validation_groups'=>'User'
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Логин*',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => ''
                )))
            ->add('email', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'E-mail*',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'example@primer.ru',
                ),
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Пороль*',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Пароль',
                )));
    }


}
```

Выше созданный тип я использую в своей форме в зависимости о ситуации

```
class RateForm extends AbstractType
{

    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Rate::class,
            'attr'=>[
                'class'=>'add-comment',
                'id' => 'rate_form'
            ]
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        $builder
            ->add('role', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Вы оставляете отзыв как:',
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,

                'class' => Role::class,
                'query_builder' =>  function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                        ->where('r.isPublish = true');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'visibleName',
            )) 
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Текст отзыва:',
                'required' => true
            ));
        if(!$user){
            $builder->add('auth', FastUserRegistrationType::class,[
                'mapped'=>false,
            ]);
        }
    }


}
```

Но условию isValid пофиг на FastUserRegistrationType

Пробовал  ставить mapped = true, но выходит ошибка, из за того что "auth", нет в сущности Rate::class

Что делать? Прошу подсказать или направить.

Comment: А где у вас constraint'ы для User::class описаны?

Comment: В сущности User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте как то так

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
if(!$user){
    $builder->add('auth', FastUserRegistrationType::class,[
        'mapped'=>false,
        'constraints' => [
                new Assert\Valid()
            ],
    ]);
}
```